# High latency in first hop (Hitron Technologies Router)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have just moved into a new apartment and I am having some issues with sporadic bursts of high latency. Generally, when I am home alone my latency is quite low (no more than 20ms to a nearby city), but in the evenings when we are 3 people home my latency skyrockets to about 1,000ms. Additionally, my connection drops out frequently if I am not near the router.

Some factors to consider: I have a Hitron Technologies router (which supposedly has many issues with latency and poor connectivity). The internet speed is at 10MB/s which is fine for all 3 roommates to watch Netflix simultaneously. There is a chance that my landlord has an illegal setup and isn't connecting to an official ISP (I live in Colombia).

That said, I suspect that the cause of the high latency is in the router and that it needs to be replaced, but I would like to make sure before I go out to buy a new one. Is there any way to know for sure? Below I have posted my traceroutes:

**Traceroute when I am home alone**

```
> traceroute to google.com (216.58.222.206), 64 hops max, 72 byte
> packets  
> 1  192.xxx.x (192.xxx.x)  1.657 ms  2.165 ms  4.855 ms  
> 2  10.xxx.xx.xx (10.xxx.xx.xx)  11.035 ms  13.258 ms  14.399 ms  
> 3  10.xxx.xx.xx (10.xxx.xx.xx)  13.290 ms  21.557 ms  21.312 ms 
> 4  10.xxx.xx.xx (10.xxx.xx.xx)  12.116 ms  14.789 ms  11.694 ms  
> 5  10.xxx.xx.xx (10.xxx.xx.xx)  12.300 ms  13.495 ms  24.174 ms  
> 6  10.xxx.xx.xx (10.xxx.xx.xx)  22.679 ms  23.822 ms  23.853 ms  
> 7  66.249.94.52 (66.249.94.52)  21.549 ms  25.665 ms  23.311 ms  
> 8  72.14.238.123 (72.14.238.123)  20.884 ms  395.890 ms  36.784 ms  
> 9  bog02s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.222.206)  21.609 ms  20.096 ms 20.732 ms
```

**Traceroute when I am sharing the internet**

```
> 1 192.xxx.x (192.xxx.x) 3081.025 ms 30.503 ms 3.463 ms 
> 2 10.xxx.xx.xx (10.xxx.xx.xx) 17.106 ms 16.735 ms 11.846 ms 
> 3 10.xxx.xx.xx (10.xxx.xx.xx) 11.801 ms 76.747 ms 20.273 ms 
> 4 10.xxx.xx.xx (10.xxx.xx.xx) 15.000 ms * 26.670 ms 
> 5 10.xxx.xx.xx (10.xxx.xx.xx) 21.659 ms 30.307 ms 20.345 ms 
> 6 74.125.147.120 (74.125.147.120) 22.792 ms 21.118 ms 32.761 ms 
> 7 66.249.94.52 (66.249.94.52) 27.426 ms 25.205 ms 30.035 ms 
> 8 72.14.238.123 (72.14.238.123) 20.257 ms 20.611 ms 27.111 ms 
> 9 bog02s05-in-f206.1e100.net (216.58.222.206) 21.694 ms 324.198 ms 308.958 ms
```

Comment: Why not and what will?

Comment: Usually I don't have latency on the last hop, though. But you think it is more likely that it is because the connection is saturated? So I should invest in higher MB/s?

Comment: Hi Spiff, thanks for responding. Based on the traceroute, it looks like the latency is definitely in my local network. So you think that finding a router with anti-bufferbloat smart queueing will fix the latency I am experiencing?

Comment: Spiff, I did a bufferbloat test and it looks like I definitely have a bufferbloat problem! http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest/13588758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If saturating your broadband link causes latency to spike, your networking gear likely has a well known bug called bufferbloat.

There’s a trick to solve bufferbloat even if you can’t replace the router that has the bug. You can put a second, anti-bufferbloat (e.g. FQ-CoDel capable) router behind the first router, and make sure all your network’s traffic goes through the second router. Also adjust the traffic shaper on the second router to make it an ever-so-slight bottleneck in both the upstream and downstream direction. That allows its anti-bufferbloat protections (Explicit Congestion Notification and intelligent packet dropping) to kick in before bloated buffer queues can build up on the buggy devices.

One extra tricky part is that during “prime time” in the evening, your broadband bandwidth might be less than at other times of day, so you’d need to adjust your traffic shaping to make sure your router is the bottleneck. There’s a commercial product that claims to automatically do this, called IQrouter from evenroute.com. i haven’t used this product so I can’t vouch for it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. So essentially I would have to buy an anti-bufferbloat router and hook it up to the router/modem I currently have?

Comment: Yes. But if you’re on a budget, first see if you can install OpenWrt or DD-WRT on that Hitron, and enable CoDel and traffic shaping. If you don’t want the hassle of installing open source firmware and can afford the IQrouter, go that way.

Comment: Spiff, you've been very helpful so far. I just want to clarify that I have the right information (because I am not the most technical). My router is a router-modem (no separate router), but if I buy a TP-Link, for example, attach it to my current Hitron router-modem and install OpenWrt or DD-WRT on the TP-Link and enable the settings you recommended, that should do the trick? 

Thanks again for your response!

Comment: @zenben1126 Yes, you can create your own solution that way, with the one downside that it doesn't self-tune its traffic shaping as your available bandwidth fluctuates throughout the day. That's the advantage of that "IQrouter" box I mentioned; it auto-tunes itself.

Comment: The internet is usually in high use throughout the day, so perhaps just set the traffic shaping to adjust for that at all times?